# Error when syncing data to Cloud firestore when they close the app

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm working with react-native expo and firestore, everything seemed to be working fine, when I notice something strange, the problem is this, according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence) it tells me this.

> On Android and Apple platforms, offline persistence is enabled by default. To disable persistence, set the PersistenceEnabled option to false.

When I make an offline change while the app is open and reconnect to the internet, the data syncs perfectly.

The problem is when I make an offline change and close the app, while the app is fully closed, I connect to the internet and go into the app, the data created earlier while I was offline is supposed to be updated in firestore, but firestore isn't doing it, it's like I never wrote it.

this is my firebase setup
version: "^9.18.0"

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "MY.APIKEY",
  authDomain: "MY.DOMAIN",
  projectId: "MY.PROJECT",
  storageBucket: "MY.STORAGE",
  messagingSenderId: "MY.MESSAGIN",
  appId: "MY.APPID",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getFirestore(app);

export { database };
```

This is data write

```
import { arrayUnion, arrayRemove, doc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { database } from "../database/firebase";

const onSubmitEdit = async (data) => {
  const userRef = doc(database, "users", email);
  await updateDoc(userRef, { groups: arrayUnion(data) });
  await updateDoc(userRef, { groups: arrayRemove(route.params.item) });
};

const onSubmitCreate = async (data) => {
  const userRef = doc(database, "users", email);

  await updateDoc(userRef, { groups: arrayUnion(data) });
};
```

This is my onSnapshot

```
import { doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
import { database } from "../database/firebase";

const session = useSelector((state) => state.session);
const activeGroup = useSelector((state) => state.activeGroup);

useEffect(() => {
  if (session) {
    const snap = onSnapshot(
      doc(database, "users", email),
      { includeMetadataChanges: true },
      async (doc) => {
        /* TASKS */
      }
    );
    return () => {
      snap();
    };
  }
}, [activeGroup.active, session]);
```

I tried to remove the includeMetadataChanges even placing the onSnapshot without the limitations of the useEffect, but nothing works, I changed the configuration and tried a few of codes from firebase and it doesn't work either, nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on offline storage being enabled by default applies to the native SDKs for iOS and Android. It does *not* apply to the JavaScript SDK, which you seem to be [using in Expo](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#using-firebase-js-sdk). So there you will have to [enable caching explicitly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#web-version-9) as shown in the documentation too.

If you get an error message there, it may be that caching isn't possible on Expo. In that case consider exiting Expo and [using the `react-native-firebase` wrappers](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#using-react-native-firebase) for the native SDKs.

Comment: react-native-firebase isn't for everyone. Current and probably the only proper way how to use Firebase in Expo is through web SDK - all other options would need app to be ejected what is something what most Expo devs doesn't want to do as it's it leads to loosing many benefits and simplicity of expo package.

Would be really great if there would be way, or at least some workaround how to make persistence work without need to use native modules.

Comment: My answer explains the options you have today. If you know of an alternative option, I recommend providing a self-answer. If you'd like to request an additional option, I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) for it rather.

Comment: Thank you very much Frank Van Puffelen 